# How to use basic auth URL in html iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, iframe

Here I am trying to use an iframe to show a website and that website is using basic auth to authenticate before opening. the basic auth url is something like user:pass@https://sample.com.

So when i am putting it in iframe something like `<iframe src="user:pass@https://sample.com">` it's not working.

Is there any way to set the basic auth header in javascript(ajax) for that particular url and then later just open the https://sample.com without user:pass ?

I found this example:

```
function NoCors() {


var username = "user";
    var password = "pass";

    var url = 'https://example.com/login';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(json) {
            alert("Success", json);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
        },

        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic" + btoa(username + ":" + password));
        },
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'json',
    });

}
```

^^ example is working fine to set the auth header but i want to setRequestHeader and just open the url with example.com or set this url as src of iframe.

Comment: Iframes do not use ajax to retrieve their destination source.  However, if you authenticate with the server the page is on first, and that authentication stores in cookies a token that it can use to validate the user, that cookie will also be passed along when you access the page in the iframe automatically.  That page would have to be smart enough to know to look for either the username and password, or the token to verify the authentication of the user.

Comment: Thanks @Taplar . Can i set the cookie with usrname and pass for that particular url. Because i don’t want to display the auth dialog to user.

Comment: Any user can gain access to see their cookies at any time.  It would be more appropriate to store and use these server side rather than putting them on the client side if you do not want the user to see them.

Comment: Yes @Taplar user may got the access to see cookies i am ok with this. But in my case i don’t have any control in backend my ui is communicating to backed via api only. I am getting the username, password and url from api endpoint, which i need to open from ui with that user name and password and this launching should be automated  b/c we have username and password. I am able to open the url in external tab or in same tab with id:pass@url but requirement is show that url page in ui via iframe.

Comment: Ok, but you are saying you are not wanting the user to see the username and password.  Now you are saying that you are getting these credentials from an api call.  That means currently the user can see those credentials in their developer tools network tab.  If your concern is to not have the users be able to see the credentials, that concern is already blown out of the water.  If you do not want the user to see the credentials, you **cannot** have them in plain text on the client side.

Comment: @Taplar let’s them see the credentials, b/c i don’t  have have control over api but i don’t want to show the auth dialog and ask user to put this user name and pass to login. I just want to bypass this dialog and open success page.

Comment: Is the dialog on the page in the iframe?  And you have no control over this page?

Comment: I have control over this page and in that page i am embedding an external page via iframe and that page requires basic auth to open. Let’s see this basic auth url which i am embedding via iframe as src https://app.mayaonline.io/maya-grafana/dashboard/login

Comment: Right, so if you don't have control over the external page, and the dialog is on that page, there isn't much you can do to change the behavior of that page, through javascript.

Comment: Yes. But there should be some way to post the auth token with url to bypass the dialog. Like set the auth header and loading the page

Comment: It's not an ajax request, and it's not a post.  It's a get request just as if the request were being made from a browser window/tab.

Comment: Ohh so if i pass the query para like url?id=bla&pass=bla then it should open

Comment: I have no idea.  It's entirely up to if the page you are opening expects the fields like that and how it processes them.

Comment: @rake7h Did you ever get this solved? There is an issue where Chrome 59 and later is not allowing passwords or credentials embedding in URLs for security reasons. But, I haven't found any mention of a good alternative yet. https://medium.com/@lmakarov/say-goodbye-to-urls-with-embedded-credentials-b051f6c7b6a3